# RoR - Spree - Paypal Express Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I am attempting to install paypal express checkout, I added the information in the Gemfile and ran bundle install where it ended up here.

```
gem 'spree', '1.3.2'
gem 'spree_gateway', :github => 'spree/spree_gateway', :branch => '1-3-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch => '1-3-stable'
gem 'spree_static_content', :github => 'spree/spree_static_content', :branch => '1-3-stable'
```

This is the error:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
In Gemfile:

```
spree_paypal_express (>= 0) ruby depends on
spree_core (~> 2.0.0.beta) ruby
spree_static_content (>= 0) ruby depends on
spree_core (1.3.2)
```

I am very new to Ruby/Rails, but I believe that should it support v2 of spree_core, it should support 1.3.2. Am I not?

The gemfile specifically asks for 1.3.2, would removing it resolve the issue?

What else information should I provide for more information?

If this is not a bug, how would it be possible to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In time I managed to find the answer my self. The issue as you see is the dependence of various versions of Spree. Meaning which Spree PayPal Express is expecting Spree 2.0 alpha while Spree Static Content depend on Spree 1.3.2

So the solutions was simple, to add the version that we are targeting in the Gemfile.

Here is a copy of part of the Gemfile I think will interest you.

```
  gem 'spree', '1.3.2'
  gem 'spree_gateway', :github => 'spree/spree_gateway', :branch => '1-3-stable'
  gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch => '1-3-stable'
  gem 'spree_static_content', :github => 'spree/spree_static_content', :branch => '1-3-stable'

  gem "cancan"
  gem 'spree_paypal_express', github: 'spree/spree_paypal_express', branch: '1-3-stable'
```

In above `branch: '1-3-stable'` is the key.

Once in place, run `bundle install` and you are good to go.